# Track whether users click SMS through cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, sms, tracking

When accessing the generated cloudpage URL sent through SMS, there will always be a 500 error. Even if the user tracking data is not written to the new Data Extension. However, the URL generated by publishing cloudpage on the web page can be accessed successfully.has anyone ever had such a situation? Can you give me some answers?

code in cloudpage:

```
< a href="https://support.google.com/">click it</a>
```

code in SMS content:

```
%%=redirectto(cloudpagesurl(2343))=%%
```

Comment: why are you using this function in sms, why not just the URL? for this to work correctly these subscribers need to exist in All subscribers

Comment: Hi EazyE，Because I also want to track which users have opened the link and make subsequent campaigns for these users.Can you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The RedirectTo function shouldn't be used in an SMS - it's really only for use in an email to tell the email to track the dynamic link within it.

As EazyE noted, The CloudPagesURL function will work in an SMS, but only if you've sent an email to that person before (as it's an email-based function), and only if you're using the same Contact/Subscriber Key to identify the same person.

If you want a process that will work all the time regardless of if you've sent them an email *and* you can use for your own click tracking, historically I have:

1. Created a GUID and associated it with a Contact Key
2. Created a link in the SMS to my Cloud Page using the GUID eg https://pub.email.mydomain.com/mycloudpage?id=%%=v(@GUID)=%%
3. Used the RequestParameter function on the Cloud Page to pick up the GUID
4. Used the GUID to look up the Contact

You get the benefit that you can't realistically guess another persons URL and you can personalise the Cloud Page however you like. You can log the click yourself and display content specific to the person accessing the page

Comment: Hi Jarrett bush, can you give me a case list that tells me how to operate? I'm a novice. I don't quite understand how to practice. Thank you

Comment: I've given you the steps you need to take above. You can either pre-generate the GUID's or do it on the fly using the AMPscript GUID function. If you do it on the fly you'd save them into the sending data extension into a new field called GUID (or something like that)
eg ```%%[
SET @subKey = AttributeValue("SubscriberKey") //or whatever your PK is
SET @guid = GUID()
SET @result = UpdateData("YOUR_DE_NAME", 1, "SubscriberKey", @subKey, "GUID", @guid)
]%%
Click here to go to Cloud Page - https://pub.email.mydomain.com/mycloudpage?id=%%=v(@GUID)=%%```